# How To Handle json null values in Swift?

Tags: json, swift

My application is crashing while pursing null json
I was tying to solve this issue since long time
you are the best who can assist me with this issue

```
func downloadJsonWithURLJB() {
        let url=URL(string:"http://ccm-hotels.com/RixosJBR/IOS/api/Con4s.php")
        do {
            let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
            let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let arrJSON = allContacts["Con+4"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
                    let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]

                    Con4Array.append(Con4s(DateCon4: (aObject["Date"] as? String)!, TimeCon4: (aObject["Time"] as? String)!,GuestNameCon4: (aObject["GuestName"] as? String)!, RoomCon4: (aObject["Room"] as? String)!, LimoCoCon4: (aObject["LimoCo"] as? String)!, DriverCon4: (aObject["Driver"] as? String)!, VehicleCon4: (aObject["Vehicle"] as? String)!, FlightCon4: (aObject["Flight"] as? String)!, PickUpCon4: (aObject["PickUp"] as? String)!, DropToCon4: (aObject["DropTo"] as? String)!, PaxCon4: (aObject["Pax"] as? String)!,TotalCon4: (aObject["Total"] as? String)!, CompleteCon4: (aObject["complete"] as? String)!))

                }
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableCon4.reloadData()

            }
        }
        catch {}}
```

Comment: What issue, please clarify what goes wrong? Where is your error handling? Please add `print(error)` to your `catch` and post the error (if decoding is the issue)

Comment: I strongly recommend you switch to Codable and JSONDecoder rather than JSONSerialization. A very nice tool for writing the code for you if needed: https://app.quicktype.io/?l=swift.  The reason your code crashes is because you have a lot of `!`, which mean "crash if this isn't perfect" in places that it may not be 100% perfect. As a starting point for us helping you, provide an example of the received JSON. What actual value is null in your example?

Comment: I did but there is no error appearing

Comment: @RobNapier the null value is like that:

Comment: json is currently null {"Con+4":[]}

Comment: Nothing in `{"Con+4":[]}` is "null." Is that the exact JSON string you're parsing? You should expect that to crash at `0...arrJSON>count-1`, since there are zero elements. (0...-1 is not valid)

Comment: This, BTW, is why you should almost never do things like `for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1`. What you mean here was `for aObject in arrJSON`.

Comment: @RobNapier
That wass helpful when JSON is null but when there is value i am getting this error:
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception

> Can't form Range with upperBound < lowerBound

occurs due to the ugly *objective-c-ish* `for` loop. If the array is empty the upper bound is -1 which is less than the lower bound.

In Swift **never** use index based `for` loops if the index is actually not needed.

Replace

```
for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
   let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
```

with

```
for aObject in arrJSON {
```

If you do need the index use the `enumerated()` syntax

```
for (index, aObject) in arrJSON.enumerated() {
```

or the safe half-open range operator

```
for index in 0..<arrJSON.count {
```

Other bad practices:

- **Never** load data from a remote URL with synchronous API `Data(contentsOf` not even on a background thread.
- A JSON dictionary in Swift 3+ is `[String:Any]`, never `[String:AnyObject]`.
- Variable and property names start with a lowercase letter.
- `.allowFragments` is pointless if the expected type is a collection type.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time replying to me
that was really helpful